# Getting User name + password to docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, passwords

I've really been struggling over the past few days trying to setup some docker containers and shell scripts to create an environment for my application to run in.

The tall and short is that I have a web server which requires a database to operate.  My aim is to have end users unzip the content onto their docker machine, run a build script (which just builds the relevant docker images), then run a OneTime.sh script (which creates the volumes and databases necessary), during this script, they are prompted for what user name and password they would like for the super user of the database.

The problem I'm having is getting those values to the docker image.  Here is my script:

```
# Create the volumes for the data backend database.
docker volume create --name psql-data-etc
docker volume create --name psql-data-log
docker volume create --name psql-data-lib

# Create data store database
echo -e "\n${TITLE}[Data Store Database]${NC}"
docker run -v psql-data-etc:/etc/postgresql -v psql-data-log:/var/log/postgresql -v psql-data-lib:/var/lib/postgresql -p 9001:5432 -P --name psql-data-onetime postgres-setup

# Close containers
docker stop psql-data-onetime
docker rm psql-data-onetime
docker stop psql-transactions-onetime
docker rm psql-transactions-onetime
```

And here is the docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu

#Required environment variables: USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME

# Add the PostgreSQL PGP key to verify their Debian packages.
# It should be the same key as https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

# Add PostgreSQL's repository. It contains the most recent stable release
#     of PostgreSQL, ``9.3``.
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Install ``python-software-properties``, ``software-properties-common`` and PostgreSQL 9.3
#  There are some warnings (in red) that show up during the build. You can hide
#  them by prefixing each apt-get statement with DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

# Note: The official Debian and Ubuntu images automatically ``apt-get clean``
# after each ``apt-get``

# Run the rest of the commands as the ``postgres`` user created by the ``postgres-9.3`` package when it was ``apt-get installed``
USER postgres

# Complete configuration
USER root
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && chown -R postgres /var/run/postgresql
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

# Run setup script
ADD Setup.sh /
CMD ["sh", "Setup.sh"]
```

The script 'Setup.sh' is the following:

```
echo -n " User name: "
read user
echo -n " Password: "
read password
echo -n " Database Name: "
read dbname
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql --command "CREATE USER $user WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD '$password';"
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/createdb -O $user $dbname
exit
```

Why doesn't this work? (I don't get prompted to enter the text, and it throws an error that the parameters are bad).  What is the proper way to do something like this?  It feels like it's probably a pretty common problem to solve, but I cannot for the life of me find any non convoluted examples of this behaviour.

The main purpose of this is to make life easier for the end user, so if I could just prompt them for the user name, password, and dbname, (plus calling the correct scripts), that would be ideal.

EDIT:

After running the log file looks like this:

```
 User name: 
 Password: 
 Database Name: 
Usage: /etc/init.d/postgresql {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ..]
```

EDIT 2:

After updating to CMD ["sh", "-x", "Setup.sh"]

I get:

- echo -n User name:
  +read user
  :bad variable nameuser
- echo -n Password:
  +read password
  :bad variable namepassword
- echo -n Database Name:
  +read dbname
  :bad variable dbname

Comment: I do not see where you use your setup.sh?

Comment: I copied the wrong docker file in.  Updated now.  Call is on the last line.

Comment: I do not see the point of having `USER postgres` followed by `USER root` and what gives `docker logs xxx` and `docker events`?

Comment: That's more of a hang over from the dockerfile I adapted this from.  I'm still trying to figure out what does what.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'what gives docker logs xxx and docker events'.

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/   and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what your asking, what gives them?  Do you mean what do they output after I run the scripts?

Comment: extract from https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerizing/ `docker run -d ubuntu /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"` and what gives `docker logs this_container`?

Comment: I've added the log, but it doesn't contain anything I wouldn't expect.

Comment: the logs show that the line `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` went wrong

Comment: change the last line of your Dockerfile to `CMD ["sh", "-x", "Setup.sh"]` and launch it again

Comment: Added more output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108945/discussion-between-user2915097-and-andy).